# Using MapFragment but 3rd party library requires SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the library [WizardDroid](http://wizardroid.codepond.org) which uses android.support.v4.app.Fragment internally.

In my application I use normal Fragments though (android.app.Fragment).

I also use Google Maps v2, which I retrieve in a fragment that inherits from a wizardroid class (which itself inherits from android.support.v4.app.Fragment).

```
public class CreateEventStepMap extends WizardStep
```

{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_event_map, container, false);

```
    final Event event = ((EventInfo)getActivity()).getEvent();

    final GoogleMap googleMap = ((com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


    return v;
}
```

}

So as you can see, I cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment() because findFragmentById(R.id.map) returns a support map fragment. I cannot do otherwise because I would get a compilation error.

This is the XML that the map fragment is inside:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />
```

**Everywhere else in my application I use normal fragments!**

When I run the application I get this exception:
11-08 20:47:19.178: E/AndroidRuntime(10347): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

Is this because I am mixing Fragments and support map fragments in the same application or maybe I am doing something else stupid?

If the answer is the first, would a solution be to change the code of the wizardroid library (I don't need support for versions < 4) ?

Comment: Note that Support v4 contains more than mere replacements for API<11. You may benefit from the library even if you don't support those API levels.